# How to decode &deg; to degree ASCII character in perl

Tags: perl

I have tried using :

```
my $nomIHMBloc = $1;
print decode_entities($nomIHMBloc), "\n";
$nomIHMBloc = decode_entities($nomIHMBloc), "\n";
```

but no luck. Is there any thing wrong? I got error:

```
Undefined subroutine &main::decode_entities called at "same perl file"
```

Thanks for your help.

PS:
exact code goes here:

```
    while($blocVars =~ m/\[(.*?)\]/g){
                binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';
                my $nomIHMBloc = $1;
                print decode_entities($nomIHMBloc), "\n";
                $nomIHMBloc = decode_entities($nomIHMBloc);
                print "nomIHMBloc::::::::$nomIHMBloc=============$1\n";
                print "insert into ASSOC_VAR_BLOC (ID_BLOC, ID_VAR, DOC_ID_MAQUETTAGE) VALUES ($id_bloc, (SELECT ID_VAR FROM VARIABLE WHERE NOM_IHM='$nomIHMBloc'),'$docId')\n";
    }
```

Comment: Have you actually included the module? Meaning... do you have `use HTML::Entities;`?

Comment: @Moritz Bunkus: I wouldn't have known to use `HTML::Entities` without looking it up. There's no need to be so "smart".

Comment: Well, he did have to get the idea that there's a function called `decode_entities()` from somewhere, AND the code snippet he's shown so far isn't a full-blown test case anyway (where does `$1` come from). So I was assuming he'd at least heard about `HTML::Entities` and maybe just forgot to `use` it this time.

Comment: @Moritz Bunkus: I agree. I just think your phrasing could have been better

Comment: That's probably the language barrier. I'm usually direct and don't go out of my way to be overly polite because I consider it false and phony. Several technically-minded people have no problem with direct questions and don't interpret anything more into them than I intended. Others think my manners are too hostile. Well, one group will always be disappointed ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "no luck"? Does your computer explode? ;)

Comment: I have used use HTML::Entities_Swd; which is I think similar to normal one.

Comment: @user1517650 I don't know what `HTML::Entities_Swd` is - neither does CPAN.

Answer (score 2):

Works fine here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use open ':locale';
use HTML::Entities;

# example text
'42&deg;' =~ /(.*)/; # 42°

# your code
my $nomIHMBloc = $1;
print decode_entities($nomIHMBloc), "\n";
#$nomIHMBloc = decode_entities($nomIHMBloc), "\n";
```

Your last line contained syntax errors. If you want to append a newline while assigning to a scalar, use the string concatenation operator `.`.

```
$nomIHMBloc = decode_entities($nomIHMBloc) . "\n";
```

It works on `print` because it's a list operator and takes a list of arguments, then joins them with the *output field separator* `$,` (see [perlvar](http://p3rl.org/perlvar)), which contains the empty string by default and acts like a simple string concatenation. However, output is

42°

Comment: Beware of `binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';`, it is tricky, as it expects your terminal to be configured as UTF-8 (not always true)! `use open ":locale"` instead.